# How to calculate/estimate velocity on an Android pedometer application

Tags: java, android, sensors, android-sensors, sensormanager

I've managed to implement a simple pedometer application, which seems to be working pretty well. To enhance it, I really need some kind of mechanism to estimate it's velocity, but I have no idea where or how to start  doing so.
The pedometer uses the sensor changes threshold to detect a step, and I wish to know where to take it from here. Here is the step counter part of it:

```
private SensorEventListener sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        float x = event.values[0];
        float y = event.values[1];
        float z = event.values[2];

        currentY = y;

        if(Math.abs(currentY-previousY) > threshould){
            numSteps++;
            stepsTextView.setText(String.valueOf(numSteps));
        }
        xTextView.setText(String.valueOf(x));
        yTextView.setText(String.valueOf(y));
        zTextView.setText(String.valueOf(z));

        previousY = y;


    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};
```

Comment: Are you against using GPS to pull location updates for speed calculations? Using accelerometers of any kind for speed is a rough go

Comment: Well... I have no idea how to use the GPS for that. How complicated is it? Regardless, I guess I'll check it out.

Comment: Once you have implemented a basic GPS service the method updateLocation(Location loc) will allow you to use loc.getSpeed() to get your current speed.